# C++ twoSum. Optimize memory usage

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am solving a twoSum problem.
Steps:

1. Read an input file with a following template:

```
   7
   1 7 3 4 7 9
```

First line is the target number, second line is a number sequence.

Numbers can be in range 0 < N < 999999999

If the sum of two numbers from the number sequence equals the target number, I write "1" to the output file.

If there are no numbers the sum of which equals the target number then I write "0" to the output file.

I need to optimize memory usage in my code. How can I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

ifstream f1;
vector<int> nums;
string line;
string source;
//Open input file and read it to a string
f1.open("input.txt");
while (getline(f1, line, '\n')) {
    source+=line + " ";
    } f1.close();

//Parse the string into an int vector
stringstream parser(source);
int num;
while (parser >> num) { nums.push_back(num); }

//Clear used strings
line = "";
source = "";

//Get target number
int target = nums.at(0);

//Get number sequence
nums.erase(nums.begin());
bool flag = false;

//Check number sequence for two numbers sum of which equals the target number

unordered_map<int, int> mp;

for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
  if(mp.count(nums[i])==1){
    flag = true;
    break;}
  mp[target-nums[i]]=i;
  }

//Write the result into the output file
ofstream f2;
f2.open("output.txt");
f2 << flag;
f2.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do to minimise memory usage here. First up, you don't need to read entire contents of the file into `std::string`. You can read directly into `std::vector`, or better still read the file contents into a single `int` variable and process the numbers as you go. Another thing: you do not need to use a `std::unordered_map`, because presence of the key is the only thing you are really interested in, so `std::unordered_set` is sufficient. Below a simple solution making use of that suggestions:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input {"input.txt"};

    int target;
    input >> target;
    int current_number;
    bool found = false;
    std::unordered_set<int> observed_numbers;
    while (input >> current_number) {
        if (observed_numbers.count(target - current_number) > 0) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        observed_numbers.insert(current_number);
    }
    std::ofstream output {"output.txt"};
    output << found;
}
```